# NSManagedObjectModel is nil

Tags: ios, core-data

`enter code here`I am working on an import tool, following the pattern objc.io did at https://github.com/objcio/issue-4-importing-and-fetching .

At an early point in the program, where I am creating an instance of NSManagedObjectModel from a url, it is returning nil. When I run the program, the error I get later is "Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model".

Attached is a screenshot at a breakpoint after I create the model. I've looked around here, and have verified that:

- HistologyDataImporter.xcdatamodeld belongs to HistologyDataImporter (target membership)
- The `NSString` I'm using the build the path matches the name of the model file ("HistologyDataImporter")
- I have also tried passing "mom" as the extension to `URLByAppendingPathComponent`, but the model is still nil when run.

Why is `[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL]` still returning nil?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using the wrong location. What you have is:

```
NSString *path = @"HistologyDataImporter";
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
moelURL = [modelURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"momd"];
```

If you call `fileURLWithPath:` with a relative path like this, it's assumed to be relative to the current working directory. Your code does not set the working directory, but the value for `modelURL` suggests it's somewhere in Xcode's derived data folder. That's not surprising when running the app from Xcode, but the model file is not in that directory.

You need to figure out where `HistologyDataImporter.momd` is located and make sure that `modelURL` actually points to that location. If you put the model file on your desktop, you could use the same `desktopURL` that you have in `main()` and add the model filename to that.